# Text vs str, when using python type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, annotations, python-typing

What should I use when type annotating a string, Text, or str.
What is the difference when using either?

for ex:

```
from typing import Text
def spring(a: Text) -> Text:
    return a.upper()
```

or

```
def spring(a: str) -> str:
    return a.upper()
```

Comment: The docs explain pretty well... https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Text

Comment: ohh. so it means for python3 i can use str without any hiccups @IainShelvington

Comment: it means for Python 3 they are equivalent and there is no tangible difference

Comment: got it  thanks @Iain

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the docs (As mentioned in Ians comment):

> `Text` is an alias for `str`. It is provided to supply a forward compatible path for Python 2 code: in Python 2, `Text` is an alias for `unicode`.
>
> Use Text to indicate that a value must contain a unicode string in a manner that is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3:
>
> ```py
> def add_unicode_checkmark(text: Text) -> Text:
>    return text + u' \u2713'
> ```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Text

Comment: I feel like this answer should also say: "but for Python3-only code, just use `str`."